# C++ Int to String Efficiently

Tags: c++

Is this efficient way to convert `int` to `string`?

```
int(int input) {
    int myNumber = input;
    string myString = "";
    while (myNumber > 0) {
        myString += char(myNumber % 10 + 48);
        myNumber /= 10;
    }
    //reverse
    string result = "";
    for (int i = myString.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        result += myString[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

If not, is there some more efficient way to do this without using any additional libraries?

Comment: Is `std::to_string` an option?

Comment: Define "efficient". In terms of CPU cycles, stack usage, heap usage, what? Why is this efficiency a pressing concern? What is the real-world context for the conversion? These all need justified to explain why you don't use the stdlib.

Comment: if you wrote `myNumber % 10 + '0'` instead then at least your code is portable.

Comment: But to guess at your question, I doubt this is a good way of doing it, since you allocate 2 strings and then reverse the 1st. Also, your function has no name...

Comment: @underscore_d it's also returning an int instead of a string

Comment: There is no way this is efficient. This doesn't even compile or make sense for the most part. Your function has no name and returns an int. If you fix the missing name, after you are done converting your int you are trying to return the resulting string as an int. This is going to implicitly convert it back to an int. Assuming you are using std::string (your example doesn't show what you use) this won't compile either. Even if it worked you would end up with an int again when calling this function.

Comment: Your code fails for all negative ints.

Comment: Before worrying about "efficient", you should address "correct". Does your code compile? Does it produce correct results? For integer inputs, your test cases should include at least zero, a positive number, a negative number, a small number and a large number. For example: `0`, `1`, `-8`, and `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`. Do all of these produce the results you want?

Answer (score 5):

C++ for a long time has a function within a standard library that can do that. It is [`to_string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/).

For example you can do something along the lines of:

```
int a;
std::cin >> a;
std::string aStr = std::to_string(a);
```

You should always try to use existing functions, if at all possible. There are many reasons for that:

1. Efficiency. It is likely that there exist methods more efficient than those used in the implementation of the standard library. However, often you will find that by optimising one part of the code you actually lose efficiency in another aspect. Developers of STL try to balance all the aspects.
2. Error-proneness. You are pretty much guaranteed to have more bugs in your code, then exist in the implementation of STL.
3. Interoperability with other code. Very rarely we write something to be used all by itself these days. Most of the time we want the code, that can actually function with another part of the system. And writing your own implementation of standard functions can easily break the system as the whole.
4. Future improvement. As the standards mature, your code will start working better if you use standard functions. But if you use your own... then who knows what will happen.

Comment: And for more control, the stdlib provides streams and formatting operators, which may well be "efficient" enough for the OP depending on what "efficient" means and the real-world context/frequency of such conversions.

Comment: Also under "efficiency", your standard library implementation is allowed to use platform-specific code that you couldn't write in standard C++.